# What is Perl equivalent of Python's type() function

Tags: python, perl

I can do this in Python:

```
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
```

What's the Perl equivalent?

Comment: You're assuming it has one.  The correct question is "is there a Perl equivalent?".

Comment: How does such pedantic stupidness get upvoted 5 times?

Comment: I am not referring to you. I am referring to Glenn and especially why there are a number of hostile comments in this question.  I have no idea why this question has raised anyone's ire.

Comment: @fra I know you were not referring to me. I was also surprised/saddened by the poor reception, although Glenn's comment isn't one of them (except that she should have at least said there isn't an equivalent). Probably they find it too newbie for their liking. It's seems some form of **RTFM**.

Comment: just use `+$x` or `''.$x`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perl does not make a hard distinction between strings and numbers the way that Python or Ruby do.  In Perl, the use of operators determines how the variable will be interpreted.

In Python, when you write `1 + 2`, Python checks the type of each argument, sees that they are numbers, and then performs the addition (`3`).  If you write `'1' + '2'`, it sees that both are strings, and performs concatenation (`'12'`).  And if you write `1 + '2'` you get a type error.

In Perl, when you write `1 + 2`, the `+` operator imposes numeric context on it's arguments.  Each of the arguments is converted to a number (with a subsequent warning if the argument could not be converted cleanly) and then the addition is performed (`3`).  If you write `'1' + '2'`, the arguments are still converted to numbers with a result of `3`.

If you wanted concatenation, you would use the `.` operator:  `1 . 2` which will result in `'12'` even though both of the arguments were numbers.

So since Perl's operators force a type interpretation, the variable itself does not need to (and doesn't) contain a type.  If you really need to determine which is which, you can use `Scalar::Util`'s `looks_like_number` function, but generally coding like that in Perl is indicative of a design problem.

Perl's scalar variables can contain one of 4 things:

- numbers
- strings
- the undefined value (`undef`)
- references (which can be a reference to any of the primitive types, or to objects)

The `ref` keyword is used to determine if a scalar contains a reference, and what type that reference is.

```
ref(1)         --> ''  (a false value)
ref('string')  --> ''  (a false value)
ref([1, 2, 3]) --> 'ARRAY'
ref({a => 1})  --> 'HASH'
ref(\1)        --> 'SCALAR'
ref(\\1)       --> 'REF'
ref(sub {})    --> 'CODE'
```

The full list can be found at [perldoc -f ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html)

When a reference is `bless`ed into a package, that reference becomes an object.  In that case, `ref` will return the name of the package the object is blessed into.

```
{package My::Object;
    sub new {bless {}}
}

my $obj = My::Object->new;

ref($obj)  -->  'My::Object'
```

Answer (score 6):

Try [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html).

Comment: @Tshepang how do you do... what?

Comment: @hobbs Something like `type(value)`?

Comment: @hobbs I get nothing when running `print ref(1)`.

Comment: @Tshepang vanilla Perl doesn't use strict 'int' or 'string' types. if you get nothing, it's called a scalar

Comment: @Tshepang, you must pass a reference to ref, if it is already a reference (possibly an object) that works otherwise you must include a slash (\\) to create a reference. For example `ref(\1)` gives `SCALAR`

Answer (score 4):

- [`Params::Util::_POSINT`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Params%3a%3aUtil#_POSINT_%24integer) is a good, standard way of checking if a scalar is a positive integer.
- [`Params::Util::_NONNEGINT`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Params%3a%3aUtil#_NONNEGINT_%24integer) is a good, way of checking if a scalar is a positive integer or 0.

I'm not sure why there is not an `_INTEGER` function.

If you are dealing with *objects*, then [`Scalar::Util::blessed`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3a%3aUtil#blessed) is the modern way of checking. It does what `ref` does, but does not return a value for unblessed references. (Which is what objects *are* in Perl.)

---

The beauty of Perl and TIMTOWTDI (YMMV) is that you can make it what it do what you want by combining the sniffing methods. Stick it in a module and reuse it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'isa' to test whether a target belongs to a specific class (but you have to ask if it is, not what is it).  'ref' can be used to find out what type of data a reference is, or if it isn't a reference at all.

AFAIK, there is not real equivalent because typing doesn't mean the same thing in Perl as it does in Python.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if something is an integer you could try the following:

```
use Scalar::Util;

if ( defined $value
  && !ref $value 
  && ref \$value eq 'SCALAR' 
  && Scalar::Util::looks_like_number($value)
  && $value =~ /^-?[0-9]+$/msx
) {
    printf '%s is an integer', $value;
}
```

Comment: @Tshepang Anything that isn't an object, is (or can be) a string. Including numbers. Some things that are objects can be strings too. Stop asking the wrong question.

Comment: @hobbs *Stop asking the wrong question*? What that means?

Comment: @Tshepang If I want to check the type of a variable I usually have a look into [the depths of Moose](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DROLSKY/Moose-1.24/lib/Moose/Util/TypeConstraints.pm)

Comment: The key piece of information in this answer is: There is no integer type in perl. Both strings and integers are stored as "scalars". Try these examples: `print 1 + 1`, `print "1" + 1`, `print "lemonade" + 1`.

Comment: @purinkle => this technique will fail if said `$value` is an object with overloaded numification.  And the `looks_like_number` call is redundant when followed by the regex verification.  In general, you only need the first and last condition of your `if` statement.